# ssh not looking for private key at $HOME

Tags: ssh, kubernetes, github

I have a Kubernetes pod with a persistent volume mounted at `/data`. I am trying to use the pod for remote development and as such, need to ensure that my private ssh key persists upon pod restart so I can continue to authenticate to GitHub without generating a new key.

I tried `export HOME="/data"` and pointing `ssh-keygen` to `/data/.ssh` but I was still unable to authenticate to GitHub. Presumably, ssh is not looking at `/data/.ssh` for my private key. What is the solution here? I do have control over the Dockerfile used for the pod if there is any config there that is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

To keep your private SSH key alive between pod restarts and ensure SSH uses the correct place for the key. You might attempt the following steps.

1. Include a '/data' directory within the Docker image in your Dockerfile. Then, copy your private SSH key to '/data/.ssh' and provide the key the necessary permissions.
2. When creating your pod manifest, make sure you include a PersistentVolumeClaim(PVC) to claim the desired persistent volume for '/data'.
3. Add volume and volume mount definitions to the pod specification to mount the PVC to the '/data' directory.

Follow the docs [GitHub with SSH](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh) and [Setting Up SSH Keys](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/the-ultimate-guide-to-ssh-setting-up-ssh-keys/) for more information.